# running time of bitwise operations

Tags: algorithm-analysis

Assuming we have two integers a and b, if we do bitwise operations like a & b or a | b, is the running time O(1) (constant) or is it O(b) where b is the number of bits in a and b?
Thanks!

Comment: This will depend on the model of computation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by the model of computation?